# Why is there green mold ? on my ming tree trunk and leaves are wilting and dying?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, mold

[image]I have a 40+ year old Ming Tree that has always been very lush and full, however, the leaves are now wilting and dying (they remain green but just wilt and then die). There is also blue/green mold growing on the trunk (the mold is dry and does not rub off). I have pruned the branches and they look dead inside, and each branch has a little hole in the center (not sure what this means). Please help, I hate to lose my Ming.